# Reactjs: re-renders iframes when state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an example with list and iframe in each list item.

http://jsfiddle.net/codez/kpth3szj/

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  createItem: function(item) {
      return (
          <li>{item.text} <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleDelete.bind(this, item)}>x</a><br />
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src={item.yid} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </li>        
      );
  },

  render: function() {
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(this.createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});

var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [
    {text:'hello',name:'name1',yid:'//www.youtube.com/embed/y3iZACDBapU?autoplay=1'},
    {text:'hello2',name:'name2',yid:'//www.youtube.com/embed/dA3nu8ht0jU?autoplay=1'}
    ], text: ''};
  },
  handleDelete: function(itemToDelete, e) {
    console.info(itemToDelete);
    var newItems = _.reject(this.state.items, function(item) {
        return item.name == itemToDelete.name
    });
    this.setState({items: newItems});
  },
  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} handleDelete={this.handleDelete} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.renderComponent(<TodoApp />, document.body);
```

If I remove record from state, iframes of other records are re-rendered.
If you try to remove 1st record in example, second video starts from beginning.

How tell Reactjs not to re-render records whose state does not change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a key attribute in the Todolist createitem function

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  createItem: function(item) {
      return (
          <li key={item.yid}>
              {item.text} 
              <a href="#" onClick={this.props.handleDelete.bind(this, item)}>x</a><br />
              <iframe src={item.yid} width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </li>        
      );
  },

  render: function() {
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(this.createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});
```

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children